# Are there any nice synonyms for flavour?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I did some research, and found several synonyms for *flavour*, including:

> Taste, savor, tang, seasoning, tastiness, tang, relish, bite, piquancy, pungency, spice, spiciness, and zest

However, many of these aren't too helpful, because the context is for yoghurt.

By the way, one other little question: is it correct English to say *the context is for yoghurt*?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I'd advise you to spend a little bit more time working on your questions, particularly if you intend to post a string of them in a row. People who frequent this forum are language enthusiasts, and will appreciate the effort put into making a question less haphazard and disjointed. I've made a few edits to your question to help provide some guidance, but you won't want to rely on that kind of assistance for very long. Also, there's nothing wrong with "the context is for yoghurt," but, in the future, you will want to capitalize "English" with an upper-case "E".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoghurt is usually described in terms of its [texture](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/texture), [consistency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistency), and flavour. Depending on the type of yoghurt, you can have anything from sour to sweet and spicy as its flavour.

Here's a [page full of yoghurt reviews](http://www.epicurious.com/articlesguides/everydaycooking/tastetests/greekyogurttastetest) for your inspiration.

Comment: Thank you. You hold a high standard here. I have noticed a serious need for improving my English. Sometimes I struggle to express my questions as clearly as I'd like to but I'll certainly endeavour to structure it concisely.

Comment: @Warren ‒ Organization, content, and clarity are more important in a question than is concision.  The post must not ramble; it should lay out the circumstances and your questions directly and straightforwardly, without editorializing.  Say enough to make your question quite clear; for relevant but lengthy information, use links.  Each extra second you spend improving your question will save scores of seconds on the part of readers and answerers.

Comment: Thank you. You write very well and it excites me very much to see the high standards I can reach for. I am brand new so you can expect my questions to improve drastically from here. I'm perhaps overwhelmed with the opportunity to ask the many things I've been too afraid to as a writer.